# VirtualBox - Samba, files starting with dot are read-only (i.e. .htaccess)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, samba

I've successfuly installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox in **Windows 8** and Samba extension to work with `/var/www/html` folder. It is working great except files starting with dot (`.`) like `.htaccess` or `.maintenance.php`.

The problem is I am not able to edit these files' content due to they are **read-only** (image  below). I hadn't this problem before (when I was installing VB + Ubuntu on Windows XP, I was able to edit anything) but in Windows 8, it seems that something wrong is here.

[image]
 - Read Only mode

In Windows I can see these files are hidden, so I have to have turned **Hidden items** on:

[image]

I tried setting chmod to 777, but it doesn't make them non read-only files. I can rename, delete but I am not able to edit their content.

Is there something what is needed to add/edit in Samba conf? My current file contains this part:

```
[share]
   comment = PHP Share
   path = /var/www/html
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0755
```

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solution is add `hide dot files = no` into `smb.conf`. So the config has this format:

```
[share]
   comment = PHP Share
   path = /var/www/html
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0755
   hide dot files = no
```

Now the files are not hidden and also they are not read-only.

Comment: Perfect for laravel .env not showing on samba share windows